# Extend PowerShell to search/replace and perform on all files in directory?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script that converts a CSV file to JSON. I would like to do a search/replace on the JSON file after for "NULL" to null. Also do to run this script against all CSV files in the directory. How can I extend this script to do this?

```
cd C:\example\data
import-csv .\chapters.csv | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File .\chapters.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import-csv .\chapters.csv | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | 
    Foreach {$_ -creplace 'NULL','null'} | Out-File .\chapters.json
```

The `-replace` operators can be used to replace text within a string.

Comment: Doh! Yeah that would be better. Thanks.  ;-)